# Talking bot in discord

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I had an idea that turned out to be quite problematic to solve. I am writing an entertaining bot on a discord, and I would like to add scoring for the written text using tts. I tried to do it by outputting a regular message to the channel like "/ tts Hello", but this did not help. In the documentation of discord.js I don’t even know where to find this kind of command. I will be very grateful for the command prompt responsible for this function.

P.S I am from Russia, and my English can be bad. I think the guys are smarter at the English forum, and I hope that they will help me. This is my first question on StackOverflow, so don't judge strictly

Comment: If this is a programming question, could you elaborate what you want to solve? What have you tried and what is going wrong coding wise?

Comment: Thank you, but the question has already been solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When sending a message, you can always add [`MessageOptions`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/MessageOptions), in your case `tts`

```js
message.channel.send('This is a tts message', {
 tts: true
})
```